# Getting the sums for each desired item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

I have a working code, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

The function gets the sum of appearances for each specified item and returns them as a list.

```
def question10(ipaddresses: list[str]):
    none_count = sum(1 if x is None else 0 for x in ipaddresses)
    host_count = sum(1 if x == '129.128.1.1' else 0 for x in ipaddresses)
    target_count = sum(1 if x == '192.128.1.4' else 0 for x in ipaddresses)
    return [none_count, host_count, target_count]
```

Comment: If the code works, this is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com Please also read its relevant help center pages like ['What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)'

Comment: FYI, `sum(x is None for x in ipaddresses)` also works, because `True` and `False` already act as `1` and `0`.

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You could use Counter from the collections library.

It would look something like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

def question10(ipaddresses: list[str]):
   counter = Counter(ipaddresses)
   return [counter[None], counter['129.128.1.1'], counter['192.128.1.4']]
```

Note that the `list[str]` syntax is only available in newer python versions like Python 3.9 and later.

For older versions you'd use something like:

```py
from typing import List
from collections import Counter

def question10(ipaddresses: List[str]):
    counter = Counter(ipaddresses)
    return [counter[None], counter['129.128.1.1'], counter['192.128.1.4']]
```

The usecase for these, however, will remain the same.
For example the list:

```py
ipaddresses = ['192.128.1.1', '192.128.1.4', '129.128.1.1',
               '129.128.1.1', '129.128.1.4']
```

should output `[0, 2, 1]` in both cases

Comment: Just an observation... You have a type hint of List[str] which means that your list is comprised only of str objects (i.e., homogeneous). Therefore, the list should never contain None. Of course, Python allows heterogeneous lists but you should really type hint accordingly - e.g., list[str|None]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in count() function :

```
def question10(ipaddresses: list[str]):
    none_count = ipaddresses.count(None)
    host_count = ipaddresses.count('129.128.1.1')
    target_count = ipaddresses.count('192.128.1.4')    
    return [none_count, host_count, target_count]
```